# How to display multipage pdf through iframe in webpage?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I have written this but it's only displaying 1st page of pdf on iOS Browsers.

```
<iframe type="application/pdf" src="<?php echo $pdf['url']; ?>" width="320px" 
  height="800px" 
 frameborder="1" scrolling="yes" align="left">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with following code.

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%"   src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo $pdf['url'];?>&embedded=true"> </iframe>
```